# scalajs: multiple apps in one project?

Tags: scala, sbt, scala.js

If I understood scalajs docs correctly it allows only one javascript generation per project.
Is there a way to avoid this limitation?

Currently I created scalajs sub project for Play framework. In this sub project I planned to create all scalajs apps for the service I am working on. Now I found this limitation and it's really confusing and annoying, because the only two solutions I can think of are:

1. create one "mega-script" which isn't acceptable for me
2. for every scalajs app create separate sub projects

They both are really not acceptable for a big project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every scalajs in it's own subproject and manage everything via SBT [MutliProject](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Multi-Project.html)
Here is somewhat complex example of play project, that has 6+ subprojects that compiles to one single file. [scala-js-binding](https://github.com/antonkulaga/scala-js-binding)
Check the Build.scala

```
    lazy val preview = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala) settings(previewSettings: _*) dependsOn shared dependsOn bindingPlay aggregate frontend

  //aggregate scalaJs

  lazy val frontend = Project(
    id   = "frontend",
    base = file("frontend")   ) dependsOn shared dependsOn binding
```

...

```
      scalajsOutputDir     := baseDirectory.value / "public" / "javascripts" / "scalajs",

//fastOptJs - not optimized (3Mb)
      compile in Compile <<= (compile in Compile) dependsOn (fastOptJS in (frontend, Compile)),

//fullOptJS - fully optimized (330k)
      dist <<= dist dependsOn (fullOptJS in (frontend, Compile)),
```

Comment: thanks for great example, which fits to my situation described in original question. Would have voted up twice if I could.

Answer (score 3):

Scala.js is indeed designed to generate one JavaScript output per project. There is virtually no way to change this.

However, this is not a restriction of Scala.js. Scala/Java themselves behave the same way: you cannot generate two .jars from a single sbt project for a Scala/Java application. So I do not see why Scala.js should behave any differently.

Use [multiple projects](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Multi-Project.html) in your sbt build for this, as suggested by @user3430609.